# Move cursor and return new position, but restore original cursor position

Tags: emacs, text-cursor

I want to save the current position of the cursor at the beginning of a function so that I can restore the cursor to its original position after executing the code. So far, I have tried the following:

```
(setq my_cursor_position 15)
(do-some-stuff)
(goto-char my_cursor_position)
```

That works so far, but the position is set to a hard value of 15. I haven't found a way to directly read the position of the cursor yet. There is a function `what-cursor-position`, but it stores multiple informations (character under the cursor, line, column, and position), and I don't know how to extract the position from that.

Comment: You want to read `C-h i g (elisp)Positions`

Comment: The cursor position is called `point`, and function `point` returns its value: `(point)`. IOW, "cursor position" is the definition of "point" in Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [save-excursion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/save_002dexcursion.html) to save the current point location, execute a function and restore the previous point location.

Answer (score 1):

`save-excursion` is the right answer for what you're doing now. But if you need the cursor position for some other reason, it's just `(point)`.